# $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ not isomorphic to $SL(n,\mathbb R)\times \mathbb R^\ast$ when $n>1$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

If $GL(n,\mathbb R) \cong SL(n,\mathbb R) \times \mathbb R^\ast$, then the centers are isomorphic. When $n$ is even, this means that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb R^\ast &\cong \{\lambda I_n \mid \lambda\in\mathbb R^\ast\} \\
&= Z(GL(n,\mathbb R)) \\
&\cong Z(SL(n,\mathbb R)\times\mathbb R^\ast) \\
&= Z(SL(n,\mathbb R)) \times Z(\mathbb R^\ast) \\
&= \{\pm I_n\}\times\mathbb R^\ast.
\end{align*}
But this argument doesn't apply when $n>1$ is odd. For this case, I tried to use that the claim fails for $n-1$, but I haven't had success. Why does it fail for $n$ odd?

Comment: Perhaps what led you astray is the incorrectly stated problem (Problem 7-21) in my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_. I've now added a correction to my [online correction list](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim doesn't fail for $n$ odd. If we identify $\Bbb R^\times$ with the invertible scalar matrices in ${\rm GL}_n(\Bbb R)$ then we easily check that ${\rm GL}_n(\Bbb R)={\rm SL}_n(\Bbb R)\Bbb R^\times$, that $[{\rm SL}_n(\Bbb R),\Bbb R^\times]=1$ and ${\rm SL}_n(\Bbb R)\cap\Bbb R^\times=1$, so we conclude that ${\rm GL}_n(\Bbb R)$ is an internal direct product of ${\rm SL}_n(\Bbb R)$ and $\Bbb R^\times$. The first and third facts both fail if the $n$ is even, so this doesn't work then.

Wikipedia even lists it in the example section of its article on direct products of groups.

Comment: Re: your suggested edit 5space, I am not missing the $\times$. Proving $G=H\times K$ is an internal direct product when $H,K\le G$ are subgroups means proving three things: (i) $G=HK$ (that's $HK=\{hk:h\in H,k\in K\}$ without the $\times$ symbol), (ii) $[H,K]=1$ (equivalent to every $h\in H$ commuting with every $k\in K$), and (iii) $H\cap K$ is the trivial subgroup.

Comment: Oh, yes derp! I even googled this result, but I didn't get anything saying it was true for odd n :-(