# Group Isomorphism into $GL(n,\mathbb R)$

Tags: group-theory

Show that $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^\times\times SL(n,\mathbb{R})\to GL(n,\mathbb{R}),\ (r,A)\mapsto r\cdot A$ is group isomorphism iff $n$ is odd.

Obviously $\varphi$ is an injective group homomorphism for all $n\in\mathbb N$. But why is it not surjective? Let $B\in GL(n,\mathbb R)$, then $\frac{1}{\det B}B\in SL(n,\mathbb R)$, thus $\varphi((\det B,\frac{1}{\det B}B))$=B. Why does this fail for odd $n$?

Comment: This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934554/gln-mathbb-r-not-isomorphic-to-sln-mathbb-r-times-mathbb-r-ast-when?rq=1) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You've misremembered the relevant identity regarding determinants; it is

$$ \det(r A) = r^n A $$

Your analysis is proceeding as if $\det(rA) = r \det(A)$, which is usually false.

Comment: At which point do I use $\det (rA)= r\det (A)$?

Comment: @Buh: In your claim $B/\det(B) \in \mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. And maybe in your claim that it's obvious that $\varphi$ is injective as well; although maybe your error there is something else.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll think about a new idea for a proof.

Comment: @Buh: I expect the basic idea you have will work after correcting for the correct determinant identity. (and the correction will explain why $n$ must be odd)

Comment: It's because $\det$ can take negative values where I cannot construct a preimage, right?